# My app Crashes whit RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to put a layout on an another layout and I see I need to use RelativeLayout. But when I put RelativeLayout my app crashes but without RelativeLayout and only LinearLayout don't crash. here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#242729"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/lin_lay"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/splash"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_img" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="86dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But with this code it does not crash:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#242729"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/lin_lay"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/splash"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_img" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="86dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you should post your logs for the crash

Comment: but how i see the log crash @VK.N ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Blockquote android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout

look into your java activity if you find something like (LinearLayout)findviewbyId(R.id.lin_lay) change it to 
   (RelativeLayout)findviewbyId(R.id.lin_lay);  that should be enought.